# HtmlAgilityPack HtmlDocument CreateNavigator Select XPath statement not working

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

Lets say i have this XML

```
<root>
    <myEntity> // list 1
        <name>Test 1</name>
        <entityNew> // list 2
            <newName/>
            <newName/>
        </entityNew>
    </myEntity>
    <myEntity>
        <name>Test 2</name>
        <entityNew>
            <newName/>
            <newName/>
        </entityNew>
    </myEntity>
</root>
```

I want to get the entityNew list.

What I tried was this

`//myEntity[1]/entityNew` but it's not working, same as `//myEntity[position()=1]/entityNew` or something like this `//myEntity[1]//entityNew`

but when i tried it in an online XPath tester, it worked, this is the site i used http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: post the code you used and the error message you get. cheers!

Comment: Does it have to be with XPath? If it's just about getting the nodes you may have better luck with fluent notation

Comment: Why are you trying to use HTMLAgilityPack on that input that does not seem to be HTML at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling I noticed that HtmlAgilityPack is treating the node names as all lowercase and XPath is case sensitive so the queries you have tried are returning null.

I tried the following sample application (notice all node names are lowercase):

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml");
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(xml);
var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();
var iterator = navigator.Select("root//myentity[1]/entitynew");
iterator.MoveNext();
Console.WriteLine(iterator.Current.OuterXml);
```

and the output is this:

```
<entitynew> // list 2
            <newname />
            <newname />
        </entitynew>
```

Comment: Actually, I've solved this last week and forgot to close this, but this was the correct answer. Thanks!